# Python grab element in scroll box

Tags: python, selenium

How can I grab an element in a scroll box based on the text? 
I'd like to click the shoe " NAVY/NAVY/GREY (444)". I've tried

```
`color_code = '444' `
`driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(color_code)`
```

[Here's the source for the website I'm trying to navigate through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2mXO.jpg)

Highlighted is the element I'd like to grab and     `click()`

Any help/insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us the code

Comment: I'm trying to automate orders on a website. I attached a photo of the HTML from the inspect element feature on Chrome. Here's like a snippet of the lines prior to my issue. https://imgur.com/a/SFEMy4z I use the PyKeyboard() to enter a shoe and k.tap_key('Return') to enter. This page loads, and I'd like to click on the shoe with the color code "444"

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.btn-xs.btn-link.addProductColor").click
```

Comment: Does this the first element though? It looks like using this I'd have to specify data-color="23783" but I don't know the data-color codes for any of the items, I just know the color code which is in the text link, so I want to grab the element by the text "(444)"

Comment: I just kept the above code by given by image that specify a element in span

Answer (score 0):

Link text and partial link text only work on anchor tags `<a>`. Since your element  is a `<span>` you might want to use css selector or xpath to locate it. If you specifically want to click on the shoe with that colour code, you can use `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), color_code)]` provided the page only has one shoe with that colour code.

You can also use `find_elements_by_xpath` method to get a list of all the shoes with that colour code and iterate over it to perform actions

Comment: Damn that seems like a good idea. Can you explain this to me like I'm 5? I tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 444)]").click()` and  `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text()" + colorcode + ")]").click()` but no such luck. I think I'm parsing the input incorrectly.

Comment: You are very close. You just need to enclose the colorcode in single quotes and you will be good to go. `//span[contains(text(), '444')]` would work. You can open your Dev tools and in the console check the xpath by typing $x("//span[contains(text(), '444')]") if it returns one node, the xpath works!

Comment: My console output still says "can't locate element" So far I've tried '             `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 444)]")`,
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text()" + colorcode + ")]")`, `driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//span[contains(text(), '444')]""")` would it help if I show you the exact xpath of the element I'm trying to get?